# php redirect: open in jquery pop up window?

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

Can someone please help me. I am trying to make it so that after a user logs in they are redirected to a page that opens in a jquery pop up lightbox window. Is this possible?

I am trying to do it like the following although i am getting loads of syntax errors, i'm still learning php so am probably a long way off, but can someone please show me what i could do?

Thanks.

```
if (logged_in()) {
        redirect_to("dashboard.php" rel=\"shadowbox;height=300;width=500\");
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at fancybox, which lets you load content in a popup!

Comment: Dean the code i have show is the code i have tried.

Comment: This is possible,but you should add some more info about what exactly you have and want to achieve.By what I understand is you want to show the dashboard when user logs in.So,you need to have a jquery function that executes on the login page load and fetch the user data from database(I believe) using ajax if its dynamic.Keep a html div with your content to show with `display:block` when the log in page loads make it to `display:none` using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a page that executes some jquery code you can do it 2 ways:

1- Redirect from the server side (using PHP) to a php file that has all the needed jquery code, automaticaly launch this code using the `onload` event of Jquery.

2- Just insert the needed Jquery code to the login page, instead of submiting the form to another PHP (this will cause a page redirection), use a AJAX call to check if the login is OK. If the login is successfull you can then call to the jquery popup function you need.